# Saving and viewing files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting base64-encoded file content from server. Then I'm writing data into file. I checked that file is not empty after that, it means data was successfully written to file. But when I'm trying to present this file, all I get is an empty view. So what am I doin' wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFC8q.jpg)

```
[f getFile:^(NSString * _Nonnull string) {
                NSString *docsDir;
                NSArray *dirPaths;
                NSData *content = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hill.jpg"]];
               [content writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]){
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];
                UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
                 documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
                 [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
                }
        } Error:^(NSString * _Nonnull errorMessage) {

      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code snippet, Try it

```
[f getFile:^(NSString * _Nonnull string) {
                NSString *docsDir;
                NSArray *dirPaths;
                NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: string options:0];
                dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hill.jpg"]];
               [content writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]){
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];
                UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
                 documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
                 [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
                }
        } Error:^(NSString * _Nonnull errorMessage) {

      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I see you save a string into a an image file (hill.jpg). The `UIDocumentInteractionController` read file base on their extension, so they can't read this file. I think if you change your file name to hill.txt, your code could work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the content gets from the server are base64-encode, so you need to decode it.

```
NSData *imageContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:kNilOptions];
if (imageContent) {
    // save to file
}
```